# Looping through vector of variable names and applying a function (in R)

Tags: r, loops, names

so I already found some related topics but somehow failed to apply them to my case. Actually I think this one s quite straightforward:
I am trying to write a loop that will show me all unique values for each of the variables of a given data frame (let s call it "data"). I am therefore trying to apply the unqiue() fct. Here is how I thought it d work out:

```
i=0 
for (name in names(data)) {i=i+1; print(get(paste0((unique(names(data)[i])))))}
```

Guess I havent yet figured out the correct usage of get/assign/paste.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: `apply(data, 2, unique)`

Comment: perfect, thanks! as I havent worked with R for quite some time, I forgot about apply(). However, as far as I understand from ?apply this solution is limited to the application of one function at a time (correct?). If e.g. I wanted to see not the unique entries themselves but merely the number of unique entries per variable, I d need something like length(unique(...)) which can t be performed using apply(), right?. I d then have to go with `code for(name in names(data)) {print(length(unique(data[, name])))}`  from Psidom.

Comment: `apply(data, 2, function(i) length(unique(i))`

Comment: You can apply multiple functions with either `apply` or `lapply`. Examples: `lapply(data, function(i) {
  list(n=length(i), n_distinct=length(unique(i)), unique_values=unique(i))
})` or

`apply(data, 2, function(i) {
  list(n=length(i), n_distinct=length(unique(i)), unique_values=unique(i))
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a for loop to achieve this, you can do:

```
for(name in names(data)) {
    print(unique(data[, name]))
}
```

You can also use `lapply` function. `lapply(data, unique)`.

**Update**: A performance comparison between `apply` and `lapply`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = 1:1000, z = 1:1000)
microbenchmark(lapply(df, unique), apply(df, 2, unique), times = 10000)
Unit: microseconds
                 expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval
   lapply(df, unique)  41.874  47.211  69.87959  51.317  55.832 10405.64 10000
 apply(df, 2, unique) 163.390 178.580 241.17553 187.201 209.370 11389.26 10000
```

Comment: I had no idea that `lapply` worked on dataframes. Isn't `apply` a more standard way to deal with dataframes?

Comment: `lapply` ("list apply") works on lists and a data frame is just a special type of list.

Comment: Based on my experience which may be just a fault, `apply` is usually slow.